# MC-Cordova-Plugin support for Android 12 (SDK 31) - app crashes upon startup: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, cordova

I am currently trying to get our app working against SDK 31 / Android 12, but I'm running into an issue specifically with the *cordova-plugin-marketingcloudsdk* or MC-Cordova-Plugin. We are currently running the [latest version](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin/releases/tag/7.4.2.234.1) of the plugin.

I can build the app successfully, and start the app up. We manage to get to the Splash screen before the app crashes. The `adb logcat` shows that it's caused by the following error:

```
--------- beginning of crash
04-12 13:43:19.527 12122 12236 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-11-thread-1
04-12 13:43:19.527 12122 12236 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.companyname.appname, PID: 12122
04-12 13:43:19.527 12122 12236 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.companyname.appname: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
04-12 13:43:19.527 12122 12236 E AndroidRuntime: Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
04-12 13:43:19.527 12122 12236 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:382)
04-12 13:43:19.527 12122 12236 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:673)
04-12 13:43:19.527 12122 12236 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:660)
04-12 13:43:19.527 12122 12236 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.a(Unknown Source:10)
04-12 13:43:19.527 12122 12236 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.c(Unknown Source:40)
04-12 13:43:19.527 12122 12236 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.analytics.a.c$1.a(Unknown Source:83)
04-12 13:43:19.527 12122 12236 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.e.g.run(Unknown Source:17)
04-12 13:43:19.527 12122 12236 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
04-12 13:43:19.527 12122 12236 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
04-12 13:43:19.527 12122 12236 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
04-12 13:43:19.530 12122 12276 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-11-thread-2
04-12 13:43:19.530 12122 12276 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.companyname.appname, PID: 12122
04-12 13:43:19.530 12122 12276 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.companyname.appname: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
04-12 13:43:19.530 12122 12276 E AndroidRuntime: Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
04-12 13:43:19.530 12122 12276 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:382)
04-12 13:43:19.530 12122 12276 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:673)
04-12 13:43:19.530 12122 12276 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:660)
04-12 13:43:19.530 12122 12276 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.a(Unknown Source:10)
04-12 13:43:19.530 12122 12276 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.c(Unknown Source:40)
04-12 13:43:19.530 12122 12276 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.analytics.c.c$2.a(Unknown Source:189)
04-12 13:43:19.530 12122 12276 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.e.g.run(Unknown Source:17)
04-12 13:43:19.530 12122 12276 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
04-12 13:43:19.530 12122 12276 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
04-12 13:43:19.530 12122 12276 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

I've tried having a look at StackExchange and [other](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/355238/marketing-cloud-android-sdk-7-4-1-crashes-when-targeting-android-12) [people](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/360639/sf-chat-android-sdk-v4-2-1-latest-not-compatible-with-android-12) seem to be reporting this issue with other plugins but not specifically with the *cordova-plugin-marketingcloudsdk* or MC-Cordova-Plugin.

Is there any provision on the way to fix/resolve this issue?

Thanks,
bengrah

Comment: Android 12 support exists in the 8.x line of code currently and is not yet supported by our Cordova plugin (which requires 7.x of the SDK).

Comment: @BillMote thanks for commenting - can you confirm a date time/ballpark date of when the plugin is due to be updated? Google have put on a [dead drop date of 1st November](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11926878) to update existing apps - otherwise no further app updates will be accepted until the app in question targets SDK 31. Thanks.

Comment: Please reach out through your account manager.

Comment: Hi @BillMote - we've reached out to our account manager, but have said that fixing this isn't a priority at this time. I did see on [another thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/359102/111135) that there was a version released that supported Android 12 but was pulled due to another bug, but that was around 7 months ago - do you have an update on when the new version will be released?

Comment: Sorry, we do not provide timelines or comment on roadmap work in these mediums. A voice of customer request is your best resource for ensuring your needs are documented.

Answer (score 1):

The MC Android Push SDK has been updated to support Android 12. This version can be used in both the Cordova and React plugins.